# Vocês conseguem ver algum efeito de dinamismo no site quando se usa as tags [efeito] e [dinamico]?

Tags: debate, tags

Em geral essas *tags* são criadas para a pessoa tentar descrever o que ela quer, em grande parte em HTML/CSS e coisas do tipo. Quase sempre ela não classifica nada, apenas descreve e o objetivo das *tags* é classificar e não descrever.

Eventualmente uma delas até foi usadas mais tarde para algo útil diferente do objetivo original, mas sem nada importante.

Uma das dúvidas é se podemos não ter dó e mandar pro buraco negro. A outra é: quais outras *tags* estão aí só para descrever algo sem classificar nada e que podemos mandar pro inferno? (dica: olhe em HTML/CSS, tem um monte).

Além de [efeito](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/efeito) e [dinamico](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dinamico), quem sabe [grafico](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grafico) (essa não tenho tanta certeza. [transition](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/transition) e [fade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fade) seriam também? Pense bem, pode ser útil para classificar. Eu não iria com tanta certeza. E [rolamento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rolamento)? Veja outras.

Se discordarem eu prometo que serei dinamico pra arrumar isso, seja lá o que quer dizer dinamico.

Comment: vai de uma série de tags que vejo como inuteis e geralmente discordam quando debato no META pelo carinho pela tag, ou por conseguir ver uma ou outra vez que aquilo será útil, tipo tag [tag:for], sério, eu não vejo alguém seguindo o feed desta tag, muito menos querendo agrupar algo sobre o assunto, é mais provável que use o buscador direto. Eu poderia enumerar muitas aqui assim, mas ai sairia do foco que é discutir as especificadas. Por isso concordo contigo, é não ter dó e nem apego algum.

Comment: Nem é só as especificadas, estou usando pra pegar outras, mas estou querendo pegar só as que realmente são só descritivas e não classificam, algumas parecem bobas mas ajudam achar melhor alguma coisa. Estou perguntando porque essas eu não sei, pode ser que as pessoas que as usam achem diferente de mim. Eu posso achar que é só descritiva, mas pra quem pergunta e resposta nelas pode ser útil.

Comment: Nesse contexto, qual seria a diferença de classificar e descrever? Pra mim não ta muito claro

Comment: @Costamilam Classificar ajudar achar depois porque é uma categoria de coisas, a descrição só coloca a informação ali. Quando você apenas descreve acaba tendo coisas não relacionadas de alguma forma sib a mesma *tag* só porque tem alguma coisa ali. Na descrição a apalavra serve como um coringa, ela está ali no texto, então aproveita e coloca uma *tag*, já a classificação é fundamental para dizer sobre o que é, e é comum nem estar no texto sobre aquilo (não que não pode ter, mas praticamente por acidente e por redundância).

Comment: Partindo do principio que 'efeito' e 'dinâmico' seja o resultado esperado (ou ação desejada) acredito que as perguntas devam se centralizar nas ferramentas (ex: linguagens, comandos, APIs) que estão sendo usadas para se chegar ao resultado. Ou seja, uso desnecessário dessas tags.